# How to implement a vertical ProgressBar as an Activity Background

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-animation

I ran into this app concept by [Oleg Frolov](https://dribbble.com/Volorf) on Dribble.

The implementation seems pretty basic, with a horizontal ScrollView and a button which triggers the reveal animation.

I want to know :-

- How to implement the vertical ProgressBar as the background of the
  countdown activity
- How to sync the  progress of the ProgressBar, and the TextView's text change  with the Chronometer/ System clock.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

this [project](https://github.com/JaydipZala/CustomProgressBar) show you how to implement such a progress bar.

Comment: Thanks it seems like it would work. I hope the animation would be smooth.

Answer (score 1):

that is very simple to do with a custom drawable, there's no need to use libraries.

below is an **UNTESTED** example on how to do it.

```
public class CustomDrawable extends Drawable {

   private final int color1;
   private final Paint paint;
   float level;

   public CustomDrawable(int color1, int color2) {
      this.color1 = color1;
      paint = new Paint();
      paint.setColor(color2);
      paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
   }

   @Override protected boolean onLevelChange(int level) {
      invalidateSelf();
      return true;
   }

   @Override public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
      canvas.drawColor(color1);
      level = getLevel() / 100f;
      canvas.drawRect(
         0,
         canvas.getHeight() * level, // tweak this line if not drawing properly
         canvas.getWidth(),
         canvas.getHeight(), paint);
   }

   @Override public void setAlpha(int alpha) {

   }

   @Override public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter colorFilter) {

   }

   @Override public int getOpacity() {
      return 0;
   }
}
```

on the background view just use this drawable like:

```
background.setBackground(new CustomDrawable(color1, color2));
```

then to update the value u call

```
background.getBackground().setLevel(... between 0-100...);
```